# Customizing MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I wanted to customize an MPMoviePlayerController to add more control to a video player. I can add extra controls but the top buffering control is removed. How can I make it visible?

Answer (score 2):

What i understand of your question is that you want to have some extra controls on the MPMoviePlayerController.
Now i have done this in past (in OS 4.3 and sure it can be done in latest too) and to some extent it was a pain.How i did it was by digging(Looping down the hierarchy) into the subviews of the Player and Logging(NSLog) out the required component and adding or hiding the view which was required....Also i managed t determine when the buffering bar went dim and thus hiding my custom buttons accordingly using an NSTimer.
If all this sounds like you want it..let me know. and i can post some code..!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this "code sample" from the iPhone Reference Library: https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html?